# How to prove any strictly upper triangular matrices are nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra

i don't know about the Cayley-Hamilton, soooo how can i prove this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $A^n = 0$ if $A$ is an $n\times n$ strictly upper triangular matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491491/how-to-prove-an-0-if-a-is-an-n-times-n-strictly-upper-triangular-matrix)

Comment: thank you so much!